# Set images state to Flickr API Response

Tags: reactjs, axios, material-ui, flickr

I’m working on a Flickr clone, where an axios GET request is sent to retrieve photos as the user types into the input.
My current path is returning undefined. Where is the response array of objects so I know where to set the images state to? Thank you!

Search Container

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import axios from 'axios';
class Search extends Component {
  state = {
    searchText: '',
    images: []
  }

  onTextChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({searchText: e.target.value}, () => {
      axios.get('https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=ea72b9024308d54ba48382706bebb960&user_id=156981303%40N08&format=json&api_sig=f8866cedaa88ceccdfe1e1cf06dcaded')
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({images: response.???});
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.images);
    return (
      <div>
        <TextField 
        name="searchText"
        value={this.state.searchText}
        onChange={this.onTextChange}
        floatingLabelText="Search for photos"
        fullWidth={true} 
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Search;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to modify your onTextChange method to this:

```
onTextChange = e => {
this.setState({ searchText: e.target.value }, () => {
  axios
    .get(
      `https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=ea72b9024308d54ba48382706bebb960&tags=${this.state.searchText}&tag_mode=any&format=json&nojsoncallback=1`
    )
    .then(response => response.data)
    .then(response => this.setState({ images: response.photos.photo }))
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I had tried this and it has given me an error.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'photo' of undefined

It seems the array of objects is not located in 'photos' (hence the undefined) so 'photo' cannot be read.

Comment: your user_id or api_sig was probably wrong. the last edit worked for me.